# creating word2vec model syn1neg.npy extension

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-learning, word2vec, doc2vec

When creating model,there is not any more model with extension finish

> .syn1neg.npy
>
> syn0.npy

My code is below:

```
corpus= x+y
tok_corp= [nltk.word_tokenize(sent.decode('utf-8')) for sent in corpus]
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(tok_corp, min_count=1, size = 32)
model.save('/home/Desktop/test_model')

model = gensim.models.Word2Vec.load('/home/kafein/Desktop/chatbot/test_model')
```

There is only 1 model file

```
test_model
```

Which part i am wrong ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Gensim's native `.save()` only saves off parts of the model into such separate files (like `test_model.syn1neg.npy` etc) if they are larger than a certain threshold. When they're small, they get "pickled" up into the single model save file.

So there's no problem/error here. If you start training a larger model with more words, you may see those other files re-appear. (When you do, be sure to keep them alongside the main `test_model` file, if copying/moving them elsewhere – all the files together are needed to re-`load()` the model.)

Comment: If the model can be made to load faster or at once(even if slower) or is there any other way to keep the model loaded and as and when we have a query we can call it . I made a model which has been saved as 3 separate files namely, model.trainables.syn1neg.npy(414.6 mb) , model(30 mb) and model.wv.vectors.npy(414.6 mb ). Am I going correct? Also can I load them for once and use them later on for querying my inputs? As for loading the model as of whole it takes me about 5-10 minutes and I have kept the queries in a loop which starts running normally after the model has been utlized once.